# how to fix Python pep 8 recommendations with pygame constants

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

[image]

I have a problem with pep 8 and my Python code concerning Pygame constant on the next piece of code, which is sending me error E0602 "Undefined variable" when i use the pygame constant "KEYDOWN" "K_F1" K_ESCAPE"

is there any trick to solve this problem with pep8

I am a beginner and I admit that I do not find a solution to solve this problem :(

```
def run(self):
     """ start loop """
    loop = True
    while loop is True:
        self.windowSurface.blit(self.Sprite.home, (0, 0))
        self.pygame.display.flip()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_F1:
                        loop = False
                    elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `pygame.` in front of those constants should fix the PEP8 issue.

In your case, `pygame.KEYDOWN`, `pygame.K_F1`, and `pygame.K_ESCAPE`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i made the change and pylint now sends me the error E1101 "pygame module has no 'KEYDOWN' member, :( I'm cursed

Comment: That's interesting! The documentation mentions `pygame.KEYDOWN` (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html). 

Have you tried what this post suggests? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909155/cant-import-any-pygame-functions-e1101

Comment: This SO explains the E1101 issue well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012461/imports-failing-in-vscode-for-pylint-when-importing-pygame/53025854#53025854

Comment: I just tried this method again (I had tried it yesterday without success) and I still have this damn error E1101 "Module 'pygame' has no 'KEYDOWN' member"        thx for the link

Comment: You are wonderfull, thank you very much, i had to add  in the header of mi script  from pygame.constants import (
    (all constants used in mi code) MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, QUIT, MOUSEMOTION, KEYDOWN, ect...
)